# Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming (Red): can I change the color of the backlit keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron, backlight

I just received a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming laptop. It's awesome so far! I'm just really confused on how to change the backlighting on the keyboard. It's default is red. I like the red, but on the store page on Best Buy where they sell this laptop, it says you are able to change the colors for the backlighting.

So far, I've tried to google anything for an answer, but nada. Does anyone know how to change the color? The description said it was changable.

Comment: I assume you have verified all dell software is installed and doesn’t offer this feature

Answer (score 2):

Page 15/16 of the [Setup Guide](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-15-7567-laptop_setup%20guide_en-us.pdf) indicate that the unit only comes with either non-backlit, white, or red backlit keyboard.

> **Table 11. Keyboard specifications**
>   • Chiclet backlit keyboard (red/white)   NOTE: The red backlit
>   keyboard is available only in
>   specific regions.
>   • Non-backlit keyboard